# You should not have pug tags with multiple attributes

Tags: pug

## Pug mixin with computed CSS class name

My pug mixin `tweet` normally just generates this HTML:

```
<div class='col-md-3'></div>
```

I pass `tweet` the parameter `index`, which is a zero-based positive number. When `index` equals `tweetData.index` (defined elsewhere) I want the generated `div` to glow, like this:

```
<div class='blueGlow col-md-3'></div>
```

This is my attempt:

```
mixin tweet(index)
    div.collapse(class= tweetData.index === index ? "blueGlow" : undefined).col-md-3(data-index=index)
```

The error message is: `You should not have pug tags with multiple attributes.`

Comment: You can try it like this: `div.collapse.col-md-3(class=(tweetData.index === index ? "blueGlow" : undefined), data-index=index)`

Comment: That works. If you put that in an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to define attributes twice, try it like this and it should work:

```
div.collapse.col-md-3(class=(tweetData.index === index ? "blueGlow" : undefined), data-index=index)
```

Although it's just a preference, you don't need to use a div since by default pug uses a div as an element when you omit it. Also, you can minimize your conditional line by making use of the `&&` logical operator:

```
.collapse.col-md-3(class=(tweetData.index === index && "blueGlow"), data-index=index)
```