# How do I avoid Pug tags with multiple attributes?

Tags: pug

I'm learning pug, and after reading a comment [here](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/166) and adjusting it slightly, I got this Mixin:

```
mixin mainnav(i)
    ul
        li(class=(!--i) && "active")(class='home')
            a(href="/") Home
        plus other li's,
```

Then:

```
+mainnav(1)
```

To create this html:

```
<nav class="main-nav">
   <ul>
      <li class="active home"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
      other li's...
```

It creates what I want, and you can move the `'active'` class by changing the *+mainnav(x)*, but there is a warning on compile:

```
'You should not have pug tags with multiple attributes.'
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

*(I looked at the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48087962/you-should-not-have-pug-tags-with-multiple-attributes) - and tried*

```
li(class="home" && (!--i) && "active")
```

*but only 'active' got added as a class.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work just fine:

```
li.home(class= (!--i) && "active")
```